# How to define global static classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have several classes with static methods.  I'd like to access these classes from anywhere using dot notation:

```
MyClass.MyMethod
```

How do I create a global reference to these classes?  I'd like to just `#import` one header in any classes, such as common.h.  common.h could be referenced in the PCH file.

Since each of these static classes are in their own file, should I import their headers into the PCH file or use the common.h technique?  I thought PCH allowed access to anything referenced in it without having to add a header `#import` to the file you are working in.  But that doesn't seem to be the case (or I may be doing it wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to access these classes from anywhere using dot notation:
>
> ```
> MyClass.MyMethod
> ```

You can't; you'd have to use `[MyClass MyMethod]` instead.

> ... should I import their headers into the PCH file or use the common.h technique

I'd say `#import` each header individually into the PCH, which will act like "common.h" and provide the symbols globally, automatically.  There is also one less file cluttering up your source tree.

Concerns:

The use of the word `static` is troubling in your question; I think you mean "class method"?  A `static` object (function or variable) cannot be accessed outside of its compilation unit.

Comment: You are right about static.  I'm mixing up the term in the way it is used in other languages. I have it working now.  Thanks.